# Update picture on my Windows Azure Storage (Refresh)

Tags: caching, azure, refresh, blob

I've Silverlight project

and on Windows azure storage, I upload an image here :

https://******.blob.core.windows.net/profilepicture/3d5978a1-3e51-4212-b129-9ff401149bc0

i see my picture, but when i update this picture, i see my old picture (I think it's because caching), when i check with "Azure storage explorer" my picture was change...

How i can Force the refresh on my silverlight application for to see my last update?

Thanks you very much

if you have same question, ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the cache expiration for the BLOB, read this doc:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg680306.aspx

Comment: instead of posting a link, you should always copy the content here as links expire

Answer (score 1):

Best way to force a refresh is to create a new filename when replacing a blob in Azure Storage.

You should write your app to be able to know the current name dynamically, so the app is always pulling the latest one.

There are cache-control headers that you can set on the blob, but you cannot gaurantee that every intermediate proxy will honor them, so changing the filename (the Guid in your URL above) is the only solution gauranteed to work.